# Why is my @ symbol not working?

Tags: keyboard

I've never used linux before, so this may be a problem with that, but I'm trying to simply SSH into my friends webserver using the info he gave me. I looked up that the linux command to ssh is `ssh username@hostname`. I'm not trying to type that into LXTerminal but everytime I hold shift and hit the number two I don't get `@` I get `"`. Any ideas?

Comment: The `@` is mapped to the `"` key in the UK.

Comment: By the way, I know this is probably irrelevent, but if you can't be bothered to do the remapping described below, you'll probably find that `Shift`+`'` will give `@` (the key next to `;`) If I guess correctly, this is the combination that normally would give you `"`

Comment: Thank you for the keyboard combo "shift + apostrophe" to make @ symbol. It does work!
I could not put my email address in the Netflix membership sign in. Appreciate it! Other than that, the Raspberry Pi is a great learning experience!

Comment: BTW, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards) has nice pictures of both [US](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg) and [UK](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/KB_United_Kingdom.svg) layouts.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to remap your keyboard. By default it is set to a UK map.

at the command line type:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

and hit enter. locate the following line

> XKBLAYOUT=”gb”

Change the **gb** to **us**
(This assumes you want a us mapping, if not replace the gb with the two letter code for your country)

and reboot your machine.

if it pauses for a long time during the keyboard mapping stage, enter the following at the command line:

```
sudo setupcon
```

Your next reboot should be much faster.

Reference:

http://elinux.org/index.php?title=R-Pi_Troubleshooting&oldid=147362#Re-mapping_the_keyboard_with_Debian_Squeeze

Comment: Just a note, if nano's not your editor of choice the pi comes bundled with vi as well.

Comment: That is so wierd.  Just saying....

Comment: Raspbian users should make sure to see [scruss's answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1042/5538) and/or [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36729/5538) as an alternative.

Comment: The`setupcon` was crucial for me.  Until then, the keyboard locale just wouldn't get updated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Steve's answer, though correct at the time, is now somewhat out of date. In Raspbian:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and go to the **configure_keyboard** section with <kbd>`4  Internationalisation Options`</kbd> -> <kbd>`I3 Change Keyboard Layout`</kbd>

You can choose the correct keyboard type and layout from there.

Comment: Is this simply seen as a more user-friendly way of doing the exact same thing, or does this clear up additional problems that Steve's solution does not?

Comment: Under Raspbian, it at least uses the official configuration tool. It may do additional things in the background. At least it sets up the console keyboard and X keyboard with one command, rather than Steve's two.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi configuration has changed as of Jessie (2017):

1. raspi-config no longer offers `Internationalisation Options`. The `Localisation Options` has no submenu for `Change Keyboard Layout`
2. Simply setting XKBLAYOUT="us" may default to the Spanish layout.

This worked for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

And these were my settings (I'm Canadian):

```
XKBMODEL="pc104"
XKBLAYOUT="ca"
XKBVARIANT="eng"
```

For our southern neighbors:

```
XKBMODEL="pc104"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
```

There is, however, a bug with that. When you check in

```
Pi > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration
Pi > Preferences > Keyboard and Mouse.
```

it will show United States > Spanish (Latin American). I don't think it affects functionality.

---

To find out the layout you want, run this in the Terminal:

```
rc_gui
```

Then click on `Localisation` > `Set Keyboard...` and make your change. Click `OK` to close the Keyboard Layout dialog. Click `Set Keyboard...` once more. This time, the terminal window you will show:

```
Sections: ['Global']
Layouts: ['ca']
Variants: ['eng']
Options: []
```

Now you can put those into your

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard

Layouts --> XKBLAYOUT
Variants --> XKBVARIANT
```

Comment: I wanted to mention that searching for "change keyboard layout" brings up this answer that is very similar: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10103/
But it doesn't mention that the US/Canada keyboard is pc104; I guess the Rest of the World (Latin-alphabet world outside of US/Canada) uses pc105?

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't use the Terminal is going into (from the GUI), Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Localization > Set Keyboard, and set it according to where you live.