# Rii RT-MWK01 keyboard with wrong mapping

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my @ symbol not working?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/why-is-my-symbol-not-working)

The keyboard Rii RT-MWK01 works fine except that some keys do not match the characters seen by Raspberry Pi, i.e. if I press <kbd>|</kbd> the `#` character appears. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, which should result in `#` character, in fact gives `~`. How can I change the keyboard-mapping (or configure Raspbian to see the keyboard properly)?

I'm using the standard Raspbian OS that was from the beginning on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: This question has been asked before http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/why-is-my-symbol-not-working. Basically you need to remap the keyboard details available in the link above. It sounds like you want a US mapping rather than the default GB.

Comment: thanks, that helped. Please post this as an answer, so that I can choose it as answer

Comment: This question may be closed as a duplicate so it may be better to upvote one of the other question's answers.