# Keyboard layout reconfiguration not working with raspbian

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, gui, raspi-config

I'm using Raspbian and I'm trying to reconfigure my keyboard to another keyboard layout by following this post:

[Raspbian keyboard layout](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10060/raspbian-keyboard-layout)

Then I rebooted by RPI.
It changed the keyboard layout in **console mode** but the layout is still unchanged when I used the GUI (startx).

I verified the "/etc/default/keyboard" and I have the following content:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

    XKBMODEL="pc105"
    XKBLAYOUT="ca"
    XKBVARIANT=""
    XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"

    BACKSPACE="guess"
```

How can I changed the keyboard layout in the Raspbian GUI ?

I am using:

```
Linux user01 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: As a point of reference, I just cut-and-pasted your keyboard layout above to mine, and it changed the layout (shift2 and shift-3 changed, at least from the US versions)

Answer (score -1):

I was using a remote desktop connection (RDP) to test my new keyboard layout.

So, it seems the keyboard layout won't change through a RDP connection.

However, it's working if I use the keyboard directly plugged in the RPI USB port and with a HDMI display.

It would still be great if it worked through the RDP but I supposed there is another way to configure the keyboard layout through RDP...