# Set KivyPie image to German keyboard layout (PipaOS)

Tags: setup, keyboard

I just downloaded and started the raspberry KivyPie impage
[from here](http://kivypie.mitako.eu/)

According to the documentation, it is PipaOs/Raspbian based.

How can I change the keyboard language to German?

I tried

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

this works (at least it asks me all kind of keyboard questions)

at the end, the warning

*update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported*

appears twice. The keyboard layout does not change, not even after a reboot.

Any idea how this is fixable?

I currently have no internet on that pi and raspi-config is not avaible on that image

I also tried manually changing /etc/default/keyboard (as suggested [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10060))
but it has the XKBLAYOUT="de" value which should be OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspbian keyboard layout](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10060/raspbian-keyboard-layout) You can try the other method mentioned in the accepted answer to see if it works.

Comment: Alas I tried the other method before and my /etc/default/keyboard/ file has XKBLAYOUT="de". I guess that PipaOS (which is a slimmed down raspbian) took out something that prevents me from changing the layout.