# How to change keyboard layout on terminal based os?

Tags: keyboard

I cannot type (-) on my raspberry pi with omv os installed. I know I could before

Comment: Take a look [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10103/92303)! I would recommend using a search engine the next time for problems that common and simple ;).

Comment: Thank you! It worked!. Tried searching for it but I didn't find anything

Comment: Yup, you answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

follow the prompts and set your keyboard layout. Then run:

```
sudo setupcon
```

For more details take a look [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10103/92303).

Comment: The second method worked!