# How do I use the @ symbol on the Rasberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to sign in to email but its not letting me because when I try to use the @ sign " is what shows up.

I have tried using a different keyboard but nothing has helped.

I have even tried copy and pasting it from another site but it still won't let me use the @ symbol.

Comment: If Milliway's answer or the duplicate does not solve your problem, dave, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and set

```
Internationalisation Options
```

You need to set `locale` and Keyboard.
As you haven't told us where you live and what kind of keyboard it is not possible to be more specific.