# Keyboard config not working

Tags: keyboard, raspi-config, retropie

I've tried everything so far, using dpkg-reconfigure and raspi-config do the same thing, I edited /etc/default/keyboard and rebooted countless times. Set my locale in retropie_setup.sh, set my region, set it to en_US and nothing is working. My @ and " keys are still swapped, I'm just about at the end of my rope with the Model A+ and the retropie button mapper freezes every time I use that. Anyone have any other suggestions that I haven't tried?

Comment: Have you tried these suggestions http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/why-is-my-symbol-not-working/1044#1044

Comment: I did (I've not been able to comment on this for some reason on mobile). I'm going to try the 3.3 build of retropie that was just released today, so hopefully that fixes my issue.